# Managing large Android projects with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, configuration-management

I wonder, is it possible to create agile project structure for large android project?

Now project is organized as single android_module. And compile time depresses me. Project contains ~350 xml layouts, ~800 small images, so R.java generation and packaging takes very long, even if I changed only one xml layout for one activity.

My goal - allow fast complie and testrun for one single part of project

Comment: That is an impressive number of files for a mobile phone app!

Comment: I would take it a step further and say that, it is an alarmingly large number of layouts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the project up into Modules (hopefully you're doing this anyway, just structure it this way for IntelliJ too).

Then add module dependencies where required and you can Make Module - which will only recompile the parts you are interested in.